# trying to put in a method so that I can write a test case by callling that method

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angular, typescript

- I am new to typescript and angular 2.
- I am trying to include my my tabs code in typescript method and run it but its not running.
- i am trying to put in a method so that I can write a test case by callling that method.
- i used angular 2 click (click)="myFunc()" but its not working
- can you guys tell me how to fix it.
- providing my code  and error below

https://jsfiddle.net/z4vo5u5d/409/

```
error: 

VM212:11 Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
    at eval (eval at exec (VM85 typescript.js:41), <anonymous>:11:14)
    at exec (VM85 typescript.js:41)
    at HTMLDocument.runScripts (VM85 typescript.js:41)

code: 

        <li (click)="myFunc()" class="tab-link current" data-tab="tab-1">Tab One</li>
   var tab_id = $(this).attr('data-tab');

                $('ul.tabs li').removeClass('current');
                $('.tab-content').removeClass('current');

                $(this).addClass('current');
                $("#"+tab_id).addClass('current');
  }
```

Comment: @KobyDouek thanks for your reply...hey I looked at your link but not able to find out how to implement solution...can you update in my fiddle...so confusing :(

Comment: Learn Angular from a something a little more up to date: https://angular.io/tutorial. What you are looking at is from v 2 beta 7. The current version is 4.3.6.

Comment: @R.Richards hey, I am using angular 2 that's the reason I am trying to implement in angular 2...can you update in my fiddle it's so confusing. I went through the tutorials but not able to figure it out :(

Answer (score 0):

Have you declared require in import section?

```
declare var require: any;
```

Comment: I update your code in the fiddle but still its not working https://jsfiddle.net/z4vo5u5d/411/

Answer (score 0):

It's TSD issue  create local project and ,update tsd

```
npm install -g tsd@latest
```

Comment: hey it's in fiddle I won't be able to do npm in fiddle...any other solution why myFunc is not getting called :(

Comment: I aware , create and update tsd in ur own machine. I have declared and used require many times. This is not code issue it's environment issue. You can't change environment in jsfiddle

Comment: without that can't I make it work in my fiddle...since I am trying to call this method myFunc

Comment: I Appreciate, keep trying

Comment: can you tell me why I am not able to call the  myFunc method

Comment: I hope You dont have control over other components so only you are not able to access a method which is available in other component. You should bring the code into main component's template.  Currently you have written the tabs HTML code in index.html I hope. From there you don't have access to any of components. It will just print the content what you have written there

Comment: To verify this just create a this variable in components and print near the tabs , you won't see the string of the variable